# How to make css transition effect apply to all its children?

Tags: html, css

What im trying to do is make a global class

```
.animate {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s;
    -moz-transition:0.2s;
    -o-transition:0.2s;
    transition:0.2s;
}
```

and apply it as

```
<div class="element animate">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

however, whenever I try

```
.element:hover .child{
    background:#000;
}
```

it doesnt apply the transition. Is there any way to do this? or do I just have to apply .animate to every child element?

Also, about what Im trying to do, is it practical?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of applying it to every child, just use the direct child selector (`>`):

```
.animate > * {
```

An advantage of this is that you don't have to apply the `child` class to every single child. (You could also keep the child class, and do `.child {`, but that's exactly what you were trying to avoid.)

Or if you want to animate every child, regardless of its depth (i.e. `<div class='animate'><div><div>This one</div></div></div>`), do:

```
.animate * {
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks! I didnt know it was that simple. Kinda hard not having formal education.

btw, is it practical to use global styles like that? or am i better off putting it individually?

Comment: @Pa3k.m As long as you're okay with *all* the children being animated, then yes. (If you, say, only want divs animated, do `.animate > div`, etc.)

Comment: isn't it a perf issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
.animate> * {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s;
    -moz-transition:0.2s;
    -o-transition:0.2s;
    transition:0.2s;
}
```

It will select all direct child of `.animate`

If you want to select all child with class `.child` then use

```
.animate * {
    -webkit-transition:0.2s;
    -moz-transition:0.2s;
    -o-transition:0.2s;
    transition:0.2s;
}
```

Comment: I was kinda aiming for all of its children regardless of their class or id. Thanks anyway!